# weird ROC curve which fpr>tpr ,how can i improve it?

Tags: keras, scikit-learn, autoencoder, roc

I build a model which using CNN autoencoder to Detect anomalies.

```
fpr,tpr,thresholds=roc_curve(y_true=Y_test_2,y_score=X_test_2_loss,pos_label='anomaly')
roc_auc=auc(fpr,tpr)
```

After training complete, I take the reconstruction error as the anomaly score，then I plot the ROC curve

[image: ROC curve]

In this pic,at some threshold fpr>tpr...... 
Is this phenomenon serious?Is this caused by the sample distribution or the model itself?
I am very confused，how could improve my model?

Comment: This simply means that for the area where fpr>tpr your model is worse than pure guessing. On a side note, auc=.66 is not very impressive, but it might be due tot fact output cannot be learnt from the data/features you have. Is your data highly unbalanced?

Comment: thanks for your reply.My dataset has 6000 training images and 1000 test images with about anomalous:normal==1:9 .I built an imbalanced test set with very few positive samples.  I was thinking that abnormalities are rare compared to normal.Is the imbalance in the test set cause the problem? May be I have to improve my model by training to learn a more efficient feature and a lower loss. I am confused whether the problem lies with the data or the model itself.

Comment: I made progress by changing my model's loss function and adding bn layers